# adding styles directly to elements in MVC without adding class

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an actionLink  in MVC

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.someId, "SomeDetails", "SomeCase", new { userId = item.userId }, null)
```

Now i want to add color to it based on a variable i have calculated

for example if i am creating a td i am adding color to it like

```
<tr style="color:@currentColor">
```

is there a way like this to add color attribute to the actionLink that i have created? without adding `@class="someClassName"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this ,

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.someId, "SomeDetails", "SomeCase", new { userId = item.userId },  new { @style="color:"+currentColor })
```

Answer (score 2):

The fourth param you are passing null is going to take a html object. so you can pass the class or style attribute in that param

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.someId, "SomeDetails", "SomeCase", new { userId = item.userId }, ,  new { @style="color:"+@currentColor })
```